# Report Builder Expression to SUM HH:MM:SS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report, builder, reportbuilder3.0

I am very new to SQL Server and SSRS and trying to create a report using a Matrix table within report builder.

I want to sum the HH:MM:SS spent per job, per engineer, per day e.g. job 1 is 00:30:00, job 2 is 01:00:00 and job 3 is 02:45:00 so the total would be 04:15:00.

I can use the query to produce the data and pull it together in an excel pivot table but not in a matrix table.

Thanks - Andy

Comment: Break the HH:MM:SS down to only seconds, SUM them together, then use division to re-calculate HH:MM:SS

Comment: Thanks I got the report working yesterday by following the same idea. The issue I have now is the totals in the matrix table won't cope with totals over 24 h. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "won't cope" how?    what is it currently doing, and what do you want it to do instead?

Comment: The matrix has names vertical and dates horizontal with the value being the total hours worked in a day HH:MM:SS. The totals for each row if the times is over 24h do not calculate e.g. Name A 4th May = 08:00:00, 5th = 10:00:00, 6th = 07:00:00 and 7th = 04:00:00 should equal 29:00:00 however doesn't.

Comment: What does it equal, if not 29:00:00?    What is the expression you are using to calculate the total?

Comment: I will send a couple of examples tomorrow appreciate to assistance.

Comment: I’m using =Format(DateAdd("s", (SUM(Fields!SMV_Time.Value)*60), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss") to do the initial conversion which works out fine. The same expression does not however work in the total time exceed 24h, as an example the 27th is 21:35:12 and 28th is 18:02:45. I would like to display 39:37:57 but it actually displays 15:37:57 which is obviously taking off 24h. Closest I can get to is 0:39:37.9600 using this expression  =int(sum(Fields!SMV_Time.Value)/3600) & ":" & int((sum(Fields!SMV_Time.Value) Mod 3600)/60) & ":" & (sum(Fields!SMV_Time.Value) Mod 3600) Mod 60

Comment: It looks like the expression you are using at the end of your comment should return the string you want.   Try removing any formatting from the textbox.

Comment: Nothing formatted in the text box, I have just deleted the table and created a new one but still the same results

Comment: What kind of data is being returned in the SMV_Time column?

Comment: Slight error from my side in that our software displays seconds but the SQL exports in minutes so 24.27 would be an example.

Comment: Can you change the SQL so it returns seconds?

Comment: Well I’m missing something glaringly obvious with my inexperience or I have something set in report builder I don’t know. The data is pulling out in minutes as per the example and the expression  =Format(DateAdd("s", (SUM(Fields!SMV_Time.Value)*60), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss") pulls out the correct values which I have cross referenced to our management system.  It just won’t total correctly if the values are over 24h

Comment: Well that could be because of the format "HH:mm:ss".   Anything over 24 hours would not be a valid time value, so SSRS might be subtracting 24 until it is under 24 because of that format.  That's why I suggest not using a format at all.

Comment: Unfortunalty the report will be used by some people who will struggle with the concept of displaying the minute value so I really need HH:MM:SS.

Comment: I think we're talking past each other.   The answer, as I see it, is to change your SQL so that it returns SMV_Time in seconds.   Then use the expression in my answer to populate the textbox on your report.  With no format at all in the textbox, it should produce the desired results in the desired format.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a new report and put a single textbox in it.

In the expression for the value of the textbox, I hard-coded this version of your expression:

```
=int(99999/3600) & ":" & int((99999 Mod 3600)/60) & ":" & (99999 Mod 3600) Mod 60
```

And when I preview the report, I see:

> 27:46:39

So I know this works.   The format of my textbox is blank.

If you are stuck with SQL that returns a time value in minutes then you can still use this as an expression:

```
=int(sum(Fields!SMV_Time.Value * 60)/3600) & ":"
 & int((sum(Fields!SMV_Time.Value * 60) Mod 3600)/60) & ":"
 & (sum(Fields!SMV_Time.Value * 60) Mod 3600) Mod 60
```

Again, leave the format of the textbox blank, and you should get the desired results.

Comment: Agreed it just appears to be the totals that don't want to display what I need.

Comment: Thanks! that works perfectly I have just amended it slightly to format into HH:MM:SS              
=right("0" & int(sum(Fields!SMV_Time.Value)*60/3600),2) & ":" & 
right("0" & int((sum(Fields!SMV_Time.Value*60) Mod 3600)/60),2) & ":" &
right("0" & (sum(Fields!SMV_Time.Value*60) Mod 3600) Mod 60,2)